# Swift SKSpiteNode position iPhone V iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

I have positioned a node at the top left of the view in my app using the following code:

```
health = SKSpriteNode(color: .green, size: CGSize(width: progressValue, height: 50))
health.position = CGPoint(x: -self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2)
```

This positions correctly in all iPhone simulators, ranging from 5 to 7 Plus.

However, it doesn't appear in any iPad simulator. I've set the position to midX and midY and it appeared fine just not with the code shown above which works perfectly for all iPhones.

What am I missing?

Is there a different way to position nodes on the view for an iPhone v iPad instead of using multiples of the view?

Comment: I suspect you may be having issues with screen rotation on the iPad.  Have you checked the height and width of your iPad view to see what the system reports those values as?

Comment: @ScottThompson No I have not, I've never make an app iPad compatible before so I'm clueless as to how to go about it. I assumed setting all node positions with respect to the height/width of the view would work like it does with all iPhone views?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

The problem was that the scene scaleMode was set to .aspectFill which worked great for the iPhones just not for the iPads.

However .resizeFill worked perfectly so this is what I did.

```
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {

                scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill

            }else{

                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill


            }
```